# Indentation of sub-entries in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, indentation

I am using `biblatex` for generating a bibliography, and I am using `xelatex`. It is working perfectly, but in some entries my sub-entries, which should be `1em` indented, appear `1pt` or `2pt` extra indent.

It would be great if someone please help me in this regard.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,twosided]{book}
\usepackage[spacing]{biblatex} % ,
\begin{document}
\printbibliography[notkeyword=original,notkeyword={sound recording},notkeyword=nocite]
\end{document}

Comment: An MWE represent a piece of code that is complete, compiles, and duplicates the behaviour that you want to rectify. The comment you posted is therefore insufficient. Post an MWE by editing your original question, and including it as part of the original post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. by using the above code, my bibliographies are generating fine, but few sub entries indented 1 or 2pt extra, which not look good.What I want is my all sub entries should be indented in same manner rather then extra 1/2pt for few instance.

Comment: Did you read [I've just been told I have to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) Here *minimal* means that the problem is isolated and there is nothing in the sample that distracts from the error you have or the effect you desire. *Working* doesn't mean the problem is solved `:-)`, it means the code sample can be copied-and-pasted and directly compiled. Also see [How to make a ‘minimum example’](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl).

Comment: @lockstep, JosephWright Why was this closed? It's hardly "localised"